# Removing space in table with itemize environment

Tags: tables, spacing, enumerate

I have a table that has enumerate environment in it. 
The issue is that I have a blank line before the first item in the itemize environment. How can I remove it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\fu}[1]{%
%\tightlist%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]%
#1%
\end{itemize}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{0.6\textwidth}}
    \toprule
\textbf{SB Solution Component} & \textbf{BB Data Satisfied} 
\\\midrule
\textbf{Registration Module} & \fu{
\item Capability List
\item Representation List}
\\\midrule

\textbf{Sensing Data Module} & \fu{
\item Ready Signal
}
\\\midrule

\textbf{Contexts Module} & \fu{
\item Control List
\item Contexts
}
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{BB Data Satisfied for SB Solution Component}
  \label{tab:data}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be something weird about the fact that it's inside a table. When you use your `\fu{}` outside of a table, there is no space between a paragraph and an `itemize` environment. That being said, I have no idea what's going on. Sorry... I'm sure someone else will be along soon to figure it out, though.

Comment: Put  \vspace{-1em}  right before the \fu command will do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dedicated column type for this (originally posted by Donald Arseneau on c.t.t.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
%---- Itemized columns
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{i}[1]{%
    >{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}\let\\\tabularnewline
      \itemize
      \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 50pt}% for raggedright
      \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}%
    p{#1}%
    <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|i{0.6\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{SB Solution Component} &  \multicolumn{1}{p{0.6\textwidth}}{\textbf{BB Data Satisfied}} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Registration Module}   &  \item Capability List
                                      \item Representation List \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Sensing Data Module}   &  \item Ready Signal        \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Contexts Module}       &  \item Control List
                                      \item Contexts            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to the way that paragraph boxes work in columns of the `tabular` environment.  I don't understand if it's a bug or a feature; someone with a better understanding of `tabular` should see it.

For a less hacky solution than @Adam's, I suggest that you use a `minipage` instead of a `p` column in `tabular`.  Define:

```
\newcommand{\fu}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]%
    #1%
  \end{itemize}%
  \end{minipage}}
```

Then, change your tabular to:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
```

(I don't believe your `[htbp]` there was necessary.)

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but a bit of a hacky solution is to use `\vspace{...}` inside your `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\fu}[1]{%
%\tightlist%
\vspace{-9pt}
\begin{itemize}[nosep,topsep=0pt]%
#1%
\end{itemize}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[htbp]{l|p{0.6\textwidth}}
    \toprule
\textbf{SB Solution Component} & \textbf{BB Data Satisfied} 
\\\midrule
\textbf{Registration Module} & \fu{
\item Capability List
\item Representation List}
\\\midrule

\textbf{Sensing Data Module} & \fu{
\item Ready Signal
}
\\\midrule

\textbf{Contexts Module} & \fu{
\item Control List
\item Contexts
}
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{BB Data Satisfied for SB Solution Component}
  \label{tab:data}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]