# how to cancel a space?

Tags: spacing, lists

I'm trying to cancel the space made by `\item` using `\hspace{0cm}` but this haven't work. Any suggestion please ?

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
\hline
\begin{itemize} \item[-] ABC.\item[-] DEF \end{itemize} & AAA & BBB. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

Comment: `\item` causes vertical space before and after the item, and horizontal space before and after the item label. It isn't at all clear which of those spaces you want to change. Please alwys make your examples complete documents so people can use them to test answers.

Comment: Inside a table environment look at [Removing space in table with itemize environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144715/removing-space-in-table-with-itemize-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\hspace{0cm}` it seems as if you want to remove the horizontal space. This can easily be achieved with the enumitem-package. Just state the appropriate space separating your item and the label with `labelsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=0em]
     \item[-] ABC
     \item[-] DEF
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Which will give you:

[image: No space after item]

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
\hline
\begin{itemize}[before={\vspace{-\baselineskip}},topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,label=-]
\item ABC.
\item DEF 
\end{itemize} & AAA & BBB. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]
\caption[]{Description.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\vspace{0.5cm}

\end{document}
```

We use `enumitem` to customize the `itemize` environment:

- `before={\vspace{-\baselineskip}},topsep=0pt` is to remove the space above
- `itemsep=0pt` is to remove the spacing between `\item`s
- `leftmargin=*` ensures that the spacing at the left is the same as other cells
- `label=-` is to have `-` as a label instead of specifying it for every item (probably `label=--` is even better)

Output:

[image]